# Junit тесты с нужным профилем

Tags: java, spring, maven, junit

Всем привет. Есть приложение, использую spring+hibernate. В pom.xml есть два профиля. Вот они:

```
    <profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>hsqldb</id>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
                <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.0</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>mysql</id>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <version>6.0.6</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
                <version>8.5.15</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Приложение работает нормально. Профиль используется правильный (mysql). Но как указать профиль для тестов? Если выносить зависимость для hsqldb в корневую dependencies, то тесты отрабатывают. В конфигурационных файлах српинга я так же разделяю на профили. Вот профиль для hsqldb:

```
    <beans profile="hsqldb">
    <jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="HSQL">
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:db/hsqldb/initDB.sql"/>
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:db/hsqldb/populateDB.sql"/>
    </jdbc:embedded-database>
</beans>
```

Собственно тесты я запускаю с такими настройками:

```
 @ContextConfiguration({
        "classpath:spring/spring-app.xml",
        "classpath:spring/spring-db.xml",
        "classpath:spring/spring-mvc.xml"})
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles({Profiles.HSQLDB})
@Transactional
```

Собственно сама ошибка, по которой падают тесты:

```
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'databaseType' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Driver for test database type [HSQL] is not available in the classpath
```

Comment: А `mvn clean test -P hsqldb` не работает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас отсутствует HSQLDB.jar в classpath. Добавление его должно решить проблему